# How to implement a parameterized interface at runtime?

Tags: java, generics, proxy, cglib

I have checked into Java proxy's and cglib, but I haven't found any examples about how I would even go about starting this project.

Here is what I need to do.

I have an interface:

```
public interface RoadMap<T extends City>{
    public void map(T city);
}
```

I have a bunch of different types of cities as inner classes of a class called `Cities`

I want to be able to implement the interface at run time by looping through the different inner classes of the `Cities` class like so:

```
for(Class clazz : Cities.class.getDeclaredClasses()){
   //implement RoadMap interface 
}
```

All of the implementations will be identical, except for the type parameter needs to be that of type clazz (in the for loop).

Is this even possible? If so where should I start. Java Proxies and cglib talk alot about method intercepting, but that is not really what I want to do here.

Thanks

Comment: you realize that `.getDeclaredClasses()` gets *inner classes*, not subclasses, right?

Comment: Yes, I wanted inner classes

Comment: but you said "by looping through the different subclasses of the Cities class like so:"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I ended up getting this working by using Javassist and generating bytecode at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If all the implementations are identical, you just need a single implementation. Here's such an implementation which doesn't care about generic types, not using a dynamic proxy (but you could do the same using a dynamic proxy):

```
public class RoadMapFactory {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends City> RoadMap<T> createWithRawTypes() {
        return new RoadMap() {
            @Override
            public void map(City city) {
                System.out.println("I mapped this city : " + city);

            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        RoadMapFactory factory = new RoadMapFactory();
        RoadMap<SubCity1> map1 = factory.createWithRawTypes();
        map1.map(new SubCity1());
        RoadMap<SubCity2> map2 = factory.createWithRawTypes();
        map2.map(new SubCity2());
    }
}
```

Comment: should that be `new RoadMap<T>()`?

Comment: It should, but the idea was to show that you could use a raw instance and return it as a parameterized instance, since that's what you would do with a dynamic proxy.

Comment: I don't understand. Since you are creating it, shouldn't you just create it with the right parameterization?

Comment: It doesn't matter much, because the raw type is hidden behing a type-safe facade. The point is to show that, at runtime, only raw types exist. The type-safety of generic types is ensured by the compiler. So, a dynamic proxy which would basically does the same thing as the above (i.e. not caring about the actual parameterized type) would work fine. See `Collections.emptyList()` for a similar example. You thing it returns a new parameterized object each time, but in reality, it returns the same raw type empty list each time.

Comment: This would normally work. But I need the type information at Runtime to serialize and deserialize these objects.

I need to be able to say ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType)Cities.City.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0];

Comment: @CaTalyst.X: what do you mean? A class is serializable if it implements Serializable. Why would you need to know the concrete class, and why would you need a specific proxy for each subclass. You should elaborate a bit more in your question.

Comment: Not Serialize and Deserialize in the sense of Java Serialization. There are some methods to serialize into JSON and parse back out (deserialize) from JSON. The above answer wont really do the trick because I need to be able to get the concrete Type of T at runtime, which is possibly by calling getGenericInterfaces() on the class object. 

I ended up getting this to work with Javassist since it lets you set the Generic signature.